# Is there a way of resetting the database to a particular point in time (use mainly for debugging)

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm hoping to use this type of testing with datomic

-> create database

-> load lots of data (Point A)

-> do tests/ allow user interaction 
  (adds a bunch of data)

-> restore back to Point A

-> start testing again

I know there is the backup and restore commands. Can they be accessed via the datomic api?

Answer (score 3):

Datomic allows you to [include a transaction locally without having to first share it](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/samples/seattle/getting-started.clj#L283) with everyone, and a transaction can do anything to the database. So the answer would be yes,

the basic process is:

1. grab the current state of the DB, or any historical starting point.
2. create a transaction that loads lots of data to get you to point A
3. use [with](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/with) to use the database including that data to do some tests
4. make the next modifying transaction for the next set of tests
5. repeat.

The idea is that you create a local state against which to run your tests that is based on any point in history you would care to use. This allows you to run tests for old versions of your application because you can run them against old states of the original database.

Comment: I was hoping not to use `with` as I wanted the functionaly more for user testing... so anyone can mess around with it as much as they want... and then i can roll it back again after its sufficiently messed up